# Unable to connect to MySQL docker container from another container under the same network, but accessible from outside

Tags: mysql, node.js, docker

I have two containers - "node.js" and "mysql", they are both set to be on the same network. doing `docker-compose up -d` spins up containers and they are working, I can access "node.js" and "mysql" respectively from outside.

But I can't connect to "mysql" from "node.js". Is there anything I doing wrong here ?

```
version: '3'

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    env_file: .env
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    ports:
      - ${APP_PORT}:${APP_PORT}
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    networks:
      - appnet

  mysql:
    image: mysql:8.0
    restart: always
    env_file: .env
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_HOST=%
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD}
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=${DB_NAME}
      - MYSQL_USER=${DB_USERNAME}
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD}
    volumes:
      - mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - ${DB_PORT}:${DB_PORT}
    networks:
      - appnet

networks:
  appnet:

volumes:
  mysql-data:
```

To connect to MySQL, I'm using a "knex.js" package, which works fine on my local machine (same docker config)

Comment: how do you connect from inside? can you share code snipped or settings?